# grid auto-fill with column span enforces to many columns in small containers

Tags: css, css-grid

I try to achieve a grid with a flexible amount of columns using `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(Xpx, 1fr));` and have some cells span multiple columns using `grid-column-end: span Y;` as shown in the code snippet below. This works like a charm with large grid containers, the trouble starts when the container is below `Y * Xpx` (ignoring the grid gap) as then the `grid-column-end: span Y` enforces a minimum of `Y` columns even though the `auto-fill` would result in less columns due to the minimum column width constraint not being met. Hit the button to toggle a constraint on the grid container and see that when the container is constrained to 300px, then it still has 3 columns instead of only one, due to element K spanning 3 columns.

How can I configure cells to span multiple columns but in maximum the number of columns in the grid? I.e. element K should span 3 columns by default but only one (or two) if there are less columns in the grid.

Using media queries to reduce the col-span is not an option as the sizing should be dependent on the grid container width and not the viewport width. This is due to the grid being not the only thing on the page.

```js
document.getElementById('constrain-grid-width').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
const example = document.getElementById('grid-example')
if (example.style.width == '') {
    example.style.width = '300px';
} else  {
    example.style.width = '';
}
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
display: grid;
grid-gap: 10px;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
background-color: #fff;
color: #444;
}

.box {
background-color: #444;
color: #fff;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 20px;
font-size: 150%;
}

.a {
grid-column: auto / span 2;
}

.k {
grid-column: auto / span 3;
}

.g {
grid-column: auto / span 2;
grid-row: auto / span 2;
}
```

```html
 <button id="constrain-grid-width">Toggle grid container width constraint to show problem</button>
<div class="wrapper" id="grid-example">
   <div class="box a">A</div>
   <div class="box b">B</div>
   <div class="box c">C</div>
   <div class="box d">D</div>
   <div class="box e">E</div>
   <div class="box f">F</div>
   <div class="box g">G</div>
   <div class="box h">H</div>
   <div class="box i">I</div>
   <div class="box j">J</div>
   <div class="box k">K</div>
   <div class="box l">L</div>
   <div class="box m">M</div>
</div>
```

Example copied and adapted from https://gridbyexample.com/examples/code/example29.html

Comment: did you get any solution to this ?

Comment: No, I resorted to JS to set a custom property that contains the number of columns (use ResizeObserver to watch for resizes) and use that custom property in the repeat() rule. I think this is not possible with pure CSS